# Jquery picture is being displayed in first IMG tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

For a school exercise, I've received some code to take a picture with the camera from my teacher. The only thing is that when the `captureImage` function is running it saves the picture in the first IMG tag of the HTML code.

It is, however, the intention to save this picture in the DIV with the `#fotosToevoeg` ID. I tried using the append attribute to make a new div for the pictures. At the moment I couldn't find the actual place where the code saves the picture to the first IMG tag.

This is where the picture should be saved in a new DIV

```
</div>
<div class="locatieInfo marginForNav" id="fotosToevoeg">
</div>
```

This is the jQuery code for capturing the picture right now

```
function captureImage() {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      video: true
    })
    .then(function(stream) {
      var mediaStreamTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
      var imageCapture = new ImageCapture(mediaStreamTrack);
      var img = document.querySelector('img');
      imageCapture.takePhoto()
        .then(blob => {
          img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          img.onload = () => {
            URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
          }
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('takePhoto() error:', error));

      stopStreaming();
    });
}
```

I hope somebody here can help me out with this!

Comment: What about `var img = document.querySelector('#fotosToevoeg');`?

Comment: @frankenapps that would select the div, but the div can't have an image src (it could have a background, but not sure if that would need a url rather than a data blob).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> At the moment I couldn't find the actual place where the code saves the picture to the first IMG tag.

It saves it here: `document.querySelector('img')` which is the first img tag.

You can change that line to:

```
var img = $("<img>").appendTo("#fotosToevoeg")[0];
```

(as tagged jquery) which will:

- `$("<img>")` create a new image tag
- `.appendTo()` add it to the tag with that ID
- `[0]` return the new img tag as the newly attached HTML node, so the rest of your code works without changes

Answer (score 0):

you want add new DIV and New img or want append new  img to that DIV 
For add new img to that Div you can change your code to this

```
function captureImage() {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                 video: true
            })
.then(function(stream) {
  var mediaStreamTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
  var imageCapture = new ImageCapture(mediaStreamTrack);
  var img = document.createElement("img")
  imageCapture.takePhoto()
    .then(blob => {
      img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      img.onload = () => {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
      }
      document.getElementByID("fotosToevoeg").appendChild(img)
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('takePhoto() error:', error));

  stopStreaming();
});
```

}